# what is the error in my program?

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to intercept libpthred( POSIX ) function calls using LD_PRELOAD technique. First I tried to create my own shared library having the same functin names as in the pthread library. Here is an example of my own created pthread_create function which first gets the address of original pthread_create function in the pthread library, then it calls the original function in the pthread library using the function pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <pthread.h>


int pthread_create (pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, 
    void *(*start_routine) (void*), void *arg )
  {
    int return_value;
    static int (*fptr) () = 0;
    printf( "\n this is the test of LD_PRELOAD" );
    char *lError = dlerror();
    if( fptr == 0 )
    {
       fptr = ( int (*) () ) dlsym( RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create" );
       if( fptr == 0 )
       {
           (void) printf( "Error dlopen: %s", dlerror() );
           return 0;
       }
    }
    return (return_value);
  }
```

I tried to compile it in this way:

```
g++ -fPIC -g -rdynamic -c -Wall ldtest.C -lrt -lpthread -ldl
```

But its giving the following error

```
ldtest.C:26: error: too many arguments to function
```

Line 26 is this line in the program.

```
return_value = (*fptr)( thread, attr, start_routine, arg );
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem here Or is this the right way to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such line 26 in the code that you posted. Please, post *relevant* code.

If the `fptr` you use in line 26 is declared exactly as the one in your `pthread_create` above (i.e. with empty parameter list `()`), then the code will not compile as C++, since in C++ the `()` as parameter list means "no parameters at all". And you are trying to pass arguments, which is what causes the error. Declare `fptr` with the proper parameter list if you want your code to work as C++.

The declaration with `()` as parameter list will work in C code, since in C it means "unspecified parameters", but not in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `fptr` as a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns an `int`. Thus, `gcc` complains when you try calling it with three arguments.

Try redeclaring `fptr` with the proper arguments.